# deregister scripts on certain page

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, conditional-tags

i need to exclude certain scripts from running on a certain page.  i have tried this code but it's not working - when i inspect the page the scripts are still being loaded into the footer of my page.

here is my code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );

function my_deregister_javascript() {
   if ( !is_page('my-page') ) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'isotope' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'anystretch' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'imgliquid' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'retina' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'menutron' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'imagesloaded' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'myfunctions' );

     }
}
```

what am i missing?  thanks!

Comment: Can you try the priority from 100 to default which is 10. just try `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript' );`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a basic mistake in your code. The following code

```
if ( !is_page('my-page') ) {
```

means that if you are **not** on that page, **deregister** the scripts. Have a look at the [php operators](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp)

> ```
> ! ->  Not !$x True if $x is not true
> ```

Also, why not exclude this specific page when you initially enqueue these scripts, something like

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_register_javascript', 100 );

function my_register_javascript() {
   if ( !is_page('my-page') ) {

       // ENQUEUE/REGISTER SCRIPTS

     }
}
```

It is much cleaner and more efficient. I don't see the point in registerring a script and deregister it again. Rather register the scripts conditionally from the start

Answer (score 4):

Finally got ONLY my front page to not load jquery, thought I would share it to possibly save some other hack 8 hrs of hit and miss.

```
// remove jquery from ONLY the front page

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript' );
function my_deregister_javascript() {
   if ( is_home('front-page') ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
   }
}
```

NOTE: **is_page** from the initial question does not work when you want to use front-page or home in the argument must use is_home  (that cost me an hour)

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably try only enqueueing those scripts on specific pages, rather than enqueuing and then dequeuing them:

```
function wpse158453_enqueue_scripts() {
    if(!is_page('my-page')) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/js/custom.js' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse158453_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Otherwise you could try [wp_dequeue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) rather than wp_deregister_script

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've added the `!` operator to the code to align with the OP. I have upvoted the answer. If anyone objects, feel free to just rollback my change :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Remove jquery only on front page

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript' );

function my_deregister_javascript() {
  if ( is_front_page() ) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
 }
}
```

add this script in your theme **function.php** file you will resolve query

Comment: only-code answers are not good. Please, add some explanation about what the code does so any user can understand it,